# Where to find and how to install Ubuntu GUI themes?

Tags: linux, gui, desktop, theme

I tried Ubuntu several times, but I didn't stay with it for very long.  One reason was I felt the interface was boring.

Today I saw some nice themes here: the #6 in http://www.gentoo.org/main/en/shots.old-2010.xml or #2 in http://www.gentoo.org/main/en/shots.old-2011.xml

But I don't know where to find these resource and install these themes? Is this available to install just as we install some official packages from terminal or package Manager? Or do I have to contact the author personally?

Comment: I changed the title to match with the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Right from the link that you posted:

> The screenshots on this page are contributed by various Gentoo users. Information about the themes used, background images, etc. is not available through Gentoo. You will need to contact the author of the screenshot (if you can find this person) for more information.

You need to either find the information yourself, or contact the author.

That said, if you want Ubuntu, there is little use in looking at Gentoo's screenshot contest. The culture is so different: Ubuntu is supposed to be easy, while Gentoo aims to be customizable (and not easy). You'd better look at Ubuntu themes (maybe [this](http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/) and [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/themes) or something else), or be prepared to craft your own theme.

Answer (score 0):

These themes are fairly old (prior to 2011), which would not have the gtk3 themes included. So  it may not work on Ubuntu (all gtk3 apps, i.e file-roller nautilus would look just ugly)

For themes you should really consider [gnome-look.org,](http://gnome-look.org) and look for the icon themes / gtk3.0 themes.

Comment: Thanks, but the link is not working.

Comment: @user565739 ah, typo, updated link